# "Maximum Request Length Exceeded" when paging in large Datagrid

Tags: asp.net

I have a Datagrid in my asp.net Web Application, that displays about 10000 records with Paging. The Datagrid displays find but when I click on page "10" for example I get the error message as

> Maximum Request Length Exceeded

I searched online for similar questions but most of the solutions are for people who are uploading files not for `Datagrid paging problems`.

I tried adding

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
```

in my `web.config`, 
`system.webserver` section but I still got the same problem.

Comment: You are using iis7 or what..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case, you need to check the complexity of the functionality which you are doing. In your case, you are displaying a `large number of data's in your grid`.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded). If you are using `IIS 7`, you must need to add the below line of code in your web.config file as `it allows to insert a large amount of data which is required in your case`.

```
<system.webserver>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Hope this makes a sense a bit on how to handle large complexity data. :)

Comment: Thank you I tried adding this as I mentioned in my question, but it didn't work. I had to set it with "httpruntime"

Comment: try debugging your code and see where exactly it is giving error

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used the answer from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded, the following lines were missing: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: @user4612290: Glad that helped, so you can mark my post as answer that took to that reference.!!

Answer (score 3):

A postback sends back the `Viewstate` of every control. If you have a huge `DataGrid` like you do, then when the browser re-posts that to the server, this is why you are getting the exception.

Try setting `EnableViewState="false"` on your `GridView` if you do not need the `Viewstate`, so it's not so bloated and the postback is a reasonable size. But, then [you might end up with other problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478966.aspx).

The other alternative is that you increase the `maxAllowedContentLength` that I see you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm only able to alter my web.config at the moment. I had to add this property in httpruntime

Comment: Worked for me, and it was the answer I was looking for. It didn't make sense why I should have to tweak the IIS settings, since I was updating a asp.net control, not a datasource, the data was the same in both versions.